# Minimal access required to add a new Event Receiver

Tags: 2013, permissions

I created an empty SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2013 (with elevated rights). When I try to add a new Event Receiver, i get the following error:

> SharePoint Connection Error
>
> Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://site/. Make sure that
>   the Site URL is valid and that the current user has the necessary
>   permission to access the site.

When I open Power Shell as Administrator, I get the error:

> The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are
>   not registered.

When I type the command `Add-SPShellAdmin ...` I receive the error:

> Cannot access the local farm. Verify that the local farm is properly
>   configured, currently available, and that you have the appropriate
>   permissions to access the database before trying again.

I am not a sysadmin of either `SharePoint_AdminContent` or `SharePoint_Config` and I cannot add myself, and they won't make me for sure, unless it is really necessary.

My question is, what is the **minimum** of access rights that I should request in order to be able to add a new Event Receiver to a SharePoint Site?

Comment: someone with permission has to add u with Add-SPShellAdmin

Comment: Can you open central administration site? And is SharePoint installed in same machine where you are developing?

Comment: No, I don't have permission to open Central Administation site and yes, I am developing in the same machine where SharePoint is installed.